# MySQL 2 browser like sqlite3 browser?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I just got out of using SQlite3 and it had a great and easily understandable database browser.  I have the MySQL 5.5 Server installed on my windows 7 machine right now and its up and running. I just need to see the database in my application.I am brand new to MySQL and wanted to know if they had an option like this and how do I get to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) and [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/).

Comment: @JusinRoR i know you're not on a mac, but if you ever are, Sequel Pro is really great.

Answer (score 1):

When i was on Windows i found this app to be great:
http://www.heidisql.com/download.php

Heidi sql